# How to automagically update Angular libraries just like whole projects when upgrading?

Tags: angular-cli

When you run `ng update` on Angular projects it automagically changes the code base as required. How can you do the same for a TypeScript Angular Library?

If I run `ng update` on my library it just throws the following and does not upgrade any code:

```
√ Packages successfully installed.
Using package manager: npm
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 54 dependencies.
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

      Name                               Version                  Command to update
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cdk                       14.0.3 -> 14.1.0         ng update @angular/cdk
      @angular/cli                       14.0.3 -> 14.1.0         ng update @angular/cli
      @angular/core                      14.0.3 -> 14.1.0         ng update @angular/core
      @angular/material                  14.0.3 -> 14.1.0         ng update @angular/material
      ng-zorro-antd                      13.2.1 -> 13.4.0         ng update ng-zorro-antd

    There might be additional packages which don't provide 'ng update' capabilities that are outdated.
    You can update the additional packages by running the update command of your package manager.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

- update the dependencies version in package.json file
- run npm install

Comment: Wow, that downloaded the only dependency of it in the node_modules folder INSIDE the node_modules folder, which is wrong. And also created `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, which don't belong there...